# Movie "Gagarin" what is the meaning of "DTH" which gets activated during re-entry?

Tags: history

In movie "Gagarin"; towards end there is something called "DTH" which initially doesn't gets activated and it was feared spacecraft will draft away 100 km.

what exactly is this system ? Gagarin was given orders to take manual control ?

Please explain both these concepts in detail about re-entry procedure ( automatic vs manual )

Comment: "Gagarin" by Roscosmos TV? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMb1F03aYA4

Comment: I think he's referring to Gagarin: First in Space (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvnAfmG1kpQ)

Comment: This film is of terrible quality and authenticity. It's a pretty silly movie.

Comment: Trying to explain an inaccurate movie is pointless @vikramvi.

Comment: @GdD please clarify why it's "inaccurate" movie ?

Comment: @A.Rumlin which movie is authentic then ?

Comment: it is a rare, very rare movie that distorts history. Disgusting spectacle, cheap script, cheap acting, poor camera work, poor film editing (WTF https://www.startfilm.ru/images/base/film/27_05_13/big_78784_2013-05-27_205830.jpg https://www.startfilm.ru/images/base/film/27_05_13/big_78788_2013-05-27_205856.jpg ). The actors' costumes are rented at some kind of masquerade - compare with the real clothes and spacesuit in the documentary. The writers borrowed scenes from the 1961 documentary "First Flight to the Stars"- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mozN70WctEI

Comment: ... but what do you think of the soundtrack, @A.Rumlin?

Comment: @JCRM Unremarkable music.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is "ДТХ" in Russian (Russian "H" is like Latin "N" while Russian "X" is somewhat like to Latin "H"), closest to space I can find is "[детектор термохимический](https://sokrasheniya.academic.ru/7162/%D0%94%D0%A2%D0%A5)". The device is described [here](https://www.gazoanalizators.ru/DT-1.html). It is a detector that measures the trace concentrations of fuel vapor and burnable gasses in the air. It may make some sense next to the RP-LOX rocket, but I do not see how it could be critical during re-entry.

"Датчик измерения силы тока на эффекте Холла" (a current sensor using Hall effect) may have a potential for meaning, but it is also not clear where and how it may be required during the landing. "Действие террористического характера" means the "terrorist action". Hopefully not.

Google Search gives no result, Jandex (Russian search) gives the mentioned sensor, Russian Wikipedia has no such article.

I think "ДТХ" is a fictional device that only exists in the imagination of the film makers. Getting something "almost wrong" during critical phase of flight adds the desired amount of tension to the plot.